# convert certain column names with comma separated string from sql table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example , I have this table with  different column names and the Boolean value below it,

```
case1 case2 case3 case4
1     0     1     0
```

What I want to retrieve,only column names with 1 value. So, my desired results from the query should only be case1,case3

Desired Output : case1,case3

there is only one row fetch from sql query

Is there any way?

Comment: You have only 1 row or having multiple rows??

Comment: What would happen in the case of multiple records?  I think you should read all columns and handle this in your app layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use a big `case` statement:

```
select stuff(( (case when case1 = 1 then ',case1' else '' end) +
               (case when case2 = 1 then ',case2' else '' end) +
               (case when case3 = 1 then ',case3' else '' end) +
               (case when case4 = 1 then ',case4' else '' end)
             ), 1, 1, '') as columns
```

Comment: That's a big case expression.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have multiple rows.

**Query**

```
select stuff((
  (case when count(*) = sum(cast(case1 as int)) then ',case1' else '' end) + 
  (case when count(*) = sum(cast(case2 as int)) then ',case2' else '' end) + 
  (case when count(*) = sum(cast(case3 as int)) then ',case3' else '' end) + 
  (case when count(*) = sum(cast(case4 as int)) then ',case4' else '' end)), 1, 1, '')
as no_zero_columns
from your_table_name;
```

### [**`SQL Fiddle Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e158a6/1)